# Query in oracle based on a series of conditions in the same column

Tags: oracle

Basically I have a table which stores all status changes of an item (i. e. 1 -> 2 -> 9 -> 6 -> 0). Each change is commited by a user. Timestamp and the user name and new status is stored as a separate row each time status is changed. The task is to fetch all IDs of an item where status is changed from 6 to 9 by a specific user. Status change from 6 to 9 always occurs on the same day.

Currently I'm using the following query:

```
select t1.id, t1.date, t1.id_status
from (select * table1 
            where id_status = 9
            and (user = 'user1' or user = 'user2')
            and table1.date > sysdate - interval '12' month) t1
join (select * from table1 
        where id_status = 6
        and table1.date > sysdate - interval '12' month) t2
on t1.id = t2.id 
and to_char(t1.date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') = to_char(t2.date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
and t1.date > t2.date
```

Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: Please show a structure of these two tables.

Comment: There's only one table, for example let's say it has only 4 rows:
id -- date -- user -- id_status

Comment: `an item where status is changed from 6 to 9 ...` - in other words this basically means: find two adjacent records of a given item (id), in order of "timestamp" column, where the first record has the status 6 and the next one is 9, is that right ?

Comment: if we are talking about an exact ID, yes, adjacent records for it should be 6 and 9 in id_status row. but in a given table those records can be 10 or more rows apart due to other IDs having their own records.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use the [`LEAD`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LEAD.html#GUID-0A0481F1-E98F-4535-A739-FCCA8D1B5B77) or [`LAG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAG.html#GUID-68081CD0-72BE-4C0A-AA6B-AD39FFA7BCF2) functions

is that what are you looking for?

```
WITH tab AS(
SELECT 1 AS ID, 0 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 6 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 0 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID, 6 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS ID, 9 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS ID, 1 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS ID, 2 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS ID, 9 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 9 AS ID, 6 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS ID, 9 AS status FROM dual 
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT  t.ID
  ,t.status
  ,LEAD(t.status, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS next_status
  ,LEAD(t.id, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS next_id
  FROM tab t

) x
WHERE x.status = 6 AND x.next_status = 9
```

**Result:**

> ```
> ID | STATUS | NEXT_STATUS | NEXT_ID
> -: | -----: | ----------: | ------:
>  4 |      6 |           9 |       5
>  9 |      6 |           9 |      10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fdb92f2e7674693164622ef5ba8dbf57)*

Comment: it should work in theory but my table consists of more then 100k rows, so it's not feasible.

Comment: 100k is not a large number, why is it not feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` windows function and `self join` as follows:

```
SQL> WITH tab AS(
  2  SELECT 1 AS ID, 0 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2 AS ID, 6 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3 AS ID, 0 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 4 AS ID, 6 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 5 AS ID, 9 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 6 AS ID, 1 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 7 AS ID, 2 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
  9  SELECT 8 AS ID, 9 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
 10  SELECT 9 AS ID, 6 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
 11  SELECT 10 AS ID, 9 AS status FROM dual
 12  ),
 13  -- your query starts from here
 14  cte as (
 15  select id, status, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from tab
 16  )
 17  select t.id, t.status, t1.id next_id, t1.status next_status
 18    from cte t join cte t1 on t.rn + 1 = t1.rn
 19   where t.status = 6 and t1.status = 9
 20   order by t.id;

        ID     STATUS    NEXT_ID NEXT_STATUS
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         4          6          5           9
         9          6         10           9

SQL>
```

Thanks to hotfix for sample data.